# Resize Embedded SVG

Tags: xml, svg

I've got this structure for my document

```
<svg>
<rect/>
<svg>
    <g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And I want to resize the embedded svg. I tried with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" zoomAndPan="magnify" contentStyleType="text/css" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.0">
    <rect x="100" width="800" y="100" height="10" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    <svg width="10%" height="10%">
        <g>
            <path style="fill:#FF0000;" d="description" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

But using this code I can see a part of the image and not the resized image.

Comment: SVG graphics don't lose any quality if they are zoomed or resized

Comment: I don't realy understand what you are trying to achieve. is this better? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/711wr9n0/

Comment: The g tag contains a very large image. I want to reduce it so it can fit the rect.

Comment: then use the `<image>` element's `width`, `height`and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes.

Comment: Which value for preserveAspectRatio should I choose? I tried with "none" but it has no effect